# Once Again: How to Remove Option from Gutenberg Editor for Specific Block in theme.json

Tags: block-editor, theme.json

Since WP 5.8 we can define various settings in the `theme.json` which is much appreciated and really helpful. But there are still some options I cannot find, e.g. how can I remove the layout panel from the `core/group` block?

[image]

In theme.json, I tried (not sure about the `layout`-key):

```
{
    // ...
    "settings": {
        // ...
        "blocks": {
            "core/group": {
                "layout": false // or [] or {} <-- no effect
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    // ...
    "settings": {
        // ...
        "blocks": {
            "core/group": {
                "layout": {
                    "customLayout": false // <-- no effect
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The following answers here were quite close:**

- [How to remove specific panels in the editor (Gutenberg) when editing a block (via right panel)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/385789/40821)
- [How to remove unwanted panels inside InspectorControls from core blocks in Gutenberg](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/392819/40821)
- [Remove border radius setting from the Gutenberg button block?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/382442/40821)

**So my question is**

Where can I find a complete list of all the possible settings for core-blocks in `theme.json`?

Alas, the official twentytwentyone theme does not contain a such file.

Comment: It appears that this currently isn't possible: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/31980. See also: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/33374 which suggests that hiding this in the future may be a really bad idea (I still want to hide it).

Answer (score 0):

This is now [hypothetically possible in Wordpress 6.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/10/17/miscellaneous-editor-changes-in-wordpress-6-4/#disable-layout-controls-from-theme-json):

> To disable the controls for all blocks, `"allowEditing": false` should
> be added to `settings.layout`, like so:
>
> ```json
> "settings": {
>     "layout": {
>         "allowEditing": false
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> To disable the controls for individual blocks, add `"allowEditing": false` in `settings.blocks.[block name].layout`, thus:
>
> ```json
> "settings": {
>     "blocks": {
>         "core/cover": {
>             "layout": {
>                 "allowEditing": false
>             }
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

However, disabling layout makes the row/stack block variations useless since all the alignment controls disappear along with the content/wide size stuff.